# Find the differences in a row of two different dataframes that have been updated

Tags: r, dplyr, row, set-difference

I am new to R and trying to figure out how to find differences in two data sets after merging the two. I have merged the data sets with SETDIFF and found 19 different rows in the new df. However there is no way to know which of the columns have been changed. Since the df have 100s of columns it is not practical to search every row and column to find the change. Is there a way to determine the exact change in the row in the new df.

```
IP Name Address  ZIP 
1  Bob  3456 st  2012
2  Jane 2456 st  4302
3  Mike 9698 st  2398
```

Example of the old df

```
IP Name Address  ZIP 
1  Bob  3000 st  2012
2  Jane 2456 st  4302
3  Mike 9698 st  2000
```

If the new df had changes to Bobs address and Mikes ZIP, how would I do that in R. I have tried SETDIFF and COMPARE, but those did not work. I would like to only get output for the specific changes to the dataframe and in what row it happened.

EDIT: Another example, from the comments:

```
new <- data.frame(
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                        IP = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
                      Name = c("Bob", "Jack", "Jane", "Mike", "Alex", "Amy"), 
                   Address = c("3000 st", "5678 st", "2456 st", "9698 st", 
                               "9776 st", "1002 st"), 
                       ZIP = c(2012L, 1121L, 4302L, 2398L, 3476L, 4655L)
       )  

old <- data.frame(
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                        IP = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
                      Name = c("Bob", "Jane", "Mike", "Jack"), 
                   Address = c("3456 st", "2456 st", "9698 st", "5678 st"), 
                       ZIP = c(2012L, 4302L, 2012L, 1121L)
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT #2:

If you want to find new names added from the old to the new data, and the Names column is a unique identifier, you could use this on the updated example data:

```
new %>%
  filter(!Name %in% old$Name)

#  IP Name Address  ZIP
#1  5 Alex 9776 st 3476
#2  6  Amy 1002 st 4655
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this, but another approach could be to join the data to itself using Name as a key, and then reshape to identify differences between the two:

```
library(tidyverse)
new %>%
  left_join(old, by = "Name") %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Name, names_to = c("name", "src"), names_sep = "\\.") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = src, values_from = value) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(x != y) %>%
  ungroup()

## A tibble: 5 x 4
#  Name  name    x       y      
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 Bob   Address 3000 st 3456 st
#2 Jack  IP      2       4      
#3 Jane  IP      3       2      
#4 Mike  IP      4       3      
#5 Mike  ZIP     2398    2012
```

This output tells us that Bob's Address field changed, Jack, Jane, and Mike appear in different rows, and Mike's ZIP changed.

---

Original answer

The `waldo` package offers an easy way to do this:

```
waldo::compare(new, old)

#`old$Address`: "3456 st" "2456 st" "9698 st"
#`new$Address`: "3000 st" "2456 st" "9698 st"
#
#`old$ZIP`: 2012 4302 2398
#`new$ZIP`: 2012 4302 2000
```

While not visible here, the output in the console highlights the values that changed in green.

**EDIT** - A better option might be `diffdf::diffdf(new, old)`, which outputs a summary of the specific differences:

```
Differences found between the objects!

A summary is given below.

Not all Values Compared Equal
All rows are shown in table below

  =============================
   Variable  No of Differences 
  -----------------------------
   Address           1         
     ZIP             1         
  -----------------------------


All rows are shown in table below

  ===========================================
   VARIABLE  ..ROWNUMBER..   BASE    COMPARE 
  -------------------------------------------
   Address         1        3456 st  3000 st 
  -------------------------------------------


All rows are shown in table below

  ========================================
   VARIABLE  ..ROWNUMBER..  BASE  COMPARE 
  ----------------------------------------
     ZIP           3        2398   2000   
  ----------------------------------------
```

Example data in loadable form:

```
new <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                IP = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
              Name = c("Bob", "Jane", "Mike"),
           Address = c("3456 st", "2456 st", "9698 st"),
               ZIP = c(2012L, 4302L, 2398L)
       )

old <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                IP = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
              Name = c("Bob", "Jane", "Mike"),
           Address = c("3000 st", "2456 st", "9698 st"),
               ZIP = c(2012L, 4302L, 2000L)
       )
```

Comment: Thank you for this, quick question though. Does this still work if the df's are different lengths and and not in the same order?

Comment: It depends. Perhaps you can give an example of the type of mismatch you want to handle and we can make concrete suggestions.

Comment: I think there are a lot of potential edge cases that make this a harder problem than it might seem. For instance, how many of the columns need to be perfect matches for you to count them as representing fundamentally the same data, but with some variation? What if two rows in one dataframe are equally close matches for a row in the other dataframe? etc... I think it'd be difficult to come up with a general purpose approach that makes sense in all potential contexts, so it might help to know what specific situations you're wrestling with.

Comment: I will try to be specific and concise as possible. I have two data frames, one is old, and the other is and updated version of the old one. The new data frame has some added rows to it as well as rows that have one column that is different from the old df. The df's are not ordered, so it would not be able to count down from row to row. My goal is to somehow get a snapshot of every change between the two df's whether that is a new row or a single change in a column.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include that example as code we can run?

Comment: `IP <- c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L) 
Name <- c("Bob", "Jack", "Jane", "Mike", "Alex", "Amy") 
Address <- c("3000 st", "5678 st", "2456 st", "9698 st", "9776 st", "1002 st") 
ZIP <- c(2012L, 1121L, 4302L, 2398L, 3476L, 4655L) 

df1 <- data.frame(IP, Name, Address, ZIP)

df1`

Comment: `IP2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L) 
Name2 = c("Bob", "Jane", "Mike", "Jack") 
Address2 = c("3456 st", "2456 st", "9698 st", "5678 st") 
ZIP2 = c(2012L, 4302L, 2012L, 1121L)

df2 <- data.frame(IP2, Name2, Address2, ZIP2)

df2`

Comment: Thanks -- those should all go in your question, which you can edit.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also found the package 'daff' which does exactly what I needed. Will definitely be using it in the future.